# Laravel attach returns undefined method for belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a question which has many surveys. In the questions Model:

```
public function surveys()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey::class, 'survey__surveyquestions');
}
```

And in the controller when saving a new question:

```
private $questions;

public function __construct(QuestionsRepository $questions)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->questions = $questions;
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->questions->create($request->all());

    $this->questions->surveys()->attach($request->surveys);

    return redirect()->route('admin.survey.questions.index')
        ->withSuccess(trans('core::core.messages.resource created', ['name' => trans('survey::questions.title.questions')]));
}
```

But I get the following error when it gets to the attach line:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException Call to undefined method 
>   Modules\Survey\Repositories\Eloquent\EloquentQuestionsRepository::surveys()

I notice the error mentions `EloquentQuestionsRepository` but I have added no methods in there so it's just an empty class:

```
class EloquentQuestionsRepository extends EloquentBaseRepository implements QuestionsRepository
{
}
```

QuestionRepository:

```
interface QuestionsRepository extends BaseRepository
{
}
```

Comment: based on your code, can you try `$question = $this->questions->create($request->all());$question->surveys()->attach($request->surveys);`

Comment: How does `EloquentBaseRepository` looks like ?

Comment: @HanlinWang response is `(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::surveys‌​()`

Comment: @Maraboc it's the default one found in AsgardCMS so https://github.com/AsgardCms/Core/blob/master/Repositories/Eloquent/EloquentBaseRepository.php

Comment: can you also show code of QuestionsRepository?

Comment: Ok so you have two choices **first :** `$this->questions->create($request->all())->surveys‌​()->attach($request-‌​>surveys);` and the **second :** `$this->questions->create($request->all());$question->model->surveys‌​()->attach($request-‌​>surveys);`

Comment: @HanlinWang I've added the code for QuestionsRepository

Comment: @Maraboc First method gives following `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::surveys‌​()` and 2nd `Call to a member function ‌​surveys‌​() on null`

Comment: OK wait how did you initialize `$this->questions` in the controller ??

Comment: Check what `$this->questions` returns by calling `dd($this->questions)` from within the controller's method - I have a feeling you have a wrong class associated with it - as error suggests - it looks like you've initialised it with `EloquentQuestionsRepository`.

Comment: @SebastianSulinski the output is `EloquentQuestionsRepository {#698 ▼ #model: Questions {#674 ▶} }` so you could be right. I have added the construct method to my post if that helps.

Comment: It looks like that's exactly the reason why - you're injecting instance of `EloquentQuestionsRepository`, which is implementing `QuestionsRepository` - I take it you bound it to the container somewhere and it is clearly resolving to `EloquentQuestionsRepository`. I would probably remove the constructor all together and work directly on the model - let me post the code I'd use.

Comment: Please try this i had a typo in the previous comment `$this->questions->create($request->all());$this->questions->model->‌​surveys‌​()->attach(‌​$request-‌​>surveys)‌​;` !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the response to the main post - the constructor resolves the `QuestionsRepository` to instance of `EloquentQuestionsRepository`, which by the look of it is not what the `store` method needs.

What I would probably do is to make call to `create` method directly on the model and remove constructor all together - that is unless you need the instance of `QuestionsRepository` anywhere else in your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $question = Question::create($request->all());

    $question->surveys()->attach($request->surveys);

    ...

}
```

Also - I'm not sure passing `$request->all()` is the best thing to do - I'd probably use `$request->only(...)` or `$request->all(...)` specifying which items you want to get from the request rather than passing everything from the request to the `create` method.

On the other note - you could also use `Form Request`, which would validate data for your before passing it to the `store` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation